# How to deploy my db on postgresql, using flask sql-alchemy? Getting error

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

Hello Im really dying inside since the last days and its really depressing.

I created a flask app and wanted to deploy it on Render, I could manage it but now i want to uprgrade my sqlite db to Postgresql.

The flask app worked before I did one minor change. So this is the code which gives me problems:

`app.config['SQL_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') #app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db' app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

its not False = db = SqlAlchemy(app), these are two diffrent lines i didnt write it like this on the editor on Stackoverflow.

My environment variable is DATABASE_URL = postgresql://.......
I got this from Render as External Databse URl.

ps:

I changed `postgres://` to `postgresql://` and it didn't work either.

I get this Error:

> RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'
> must be set.

The error occurs on the line `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

**Update:** I could fix the Problem, I messed with my code and the Solution for this Error was app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

-closed

Comment: you should hide the database URL asap

Comment: Na its useless intel, because its only for testing purpose. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: have you tried removed app from `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`.
It works for me `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQAlchemy  db=SQLAlchemy()`

Comment: Thanks now it works, but I get following Error now: RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple 'SQLAlchemy' instances?

Comment: If you want to preserve new lines, you need triple backticks, out four-space indents.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you added `db.init_app(app) `on db in app.py uset the above mentioned `db`